# Even when place is occupied, code passes through and runs the next line.. Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python

I used my logic for this game. However I feel the code is very lengthy, can anyone help me shorten the code and help me understanding how? should I create function? Also, when the place is occupied, it should show the message "Place is already taken" which is happening only first time, second time when I enter the same number, it passes through. code is below:

```
board = [" " for i in range(9)]

def print_board():

    row1="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[0],board[1],board[2])
    row2="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[3],board[4],board[5])
    row3="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[6],board[7],board[8])

    print()
    print(row1)
    print(row2)
    print(row3)
    print()

while True:

    print_board()

    choice=int(input("enter your choice, player 1").strip())

    if board[choice-1]==" ":
        board[choice-1]= "X"
        print_board()

    else:

        print("space is taken, try again")
        choice=int(input("enter your choice, player 1").strip())
        if board[choice-1]==" ": 
            board[choice-1]= "X"
            print_board() 


    choice=int(input("enter your choice, player 2").strip())

    if board[choice-1]==" ":
        board[choice-1]= "0"
    else:
        print("space is taken")
        choice=int(input("enter your choice, player 2").strip())
        if board[choice-1]==" ":

            board[choice-1]= "X"
            print_board()
```

Comment: To shorten code look for parts of code which are nearly identical (for example your else branch) and determine variable parts to be used as parameters. There are a few rules of thumbs for functions: about 0 to three parameters, and about 10 to 20 lines of code max. This may vary depending on context and use case. Also one function should have exactly one purpose/task - and this task provides the the name for the function. Your function `print_board` is one example: it does one thing and uses ony a few lines of code.

Comment: @Loebl thanks for this, I will take some time to understand the things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
board = [" " for i in range(9)]

def print_board():

    row1="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[0],board[1],board[2])
    row2="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[3],board[4],board[5])
    row3="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[6],board[7],board[8])

    print("\n" + row1 + "\n" + row2 + "\n" + row3 + "\n")

def verify(numPlayer):
    choice=int(input("enter your choice, player " + str(numPlayer)).strip())
    while board[choice-1]!=" ": #while the coice of user is not a empty slot. You hadn't verify his second choice and he could put in another occupied slot
        print("space is taken, try again")
        choice=int(input("enter your choice, player " + str(numPlayer)).strip())
        #You have to verify also if there is an empty slot

     if numPlayer ==1:
         board[choice-1]= "X"
     else: 
         board[choice-1]= "0"


while True:
   print_board()
    verify(1)
    print_board()
    verify(2)
    print_board()
```

Comment: @KumarKatariya what you want as output?

Comment: @JoãoCastilho I get the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/getyoteam/Documents/Tic_try.py", line 24, in <module>
    verify(1)
  File "/Users/getyoteam/Documents/Tic_try.py", line 13, in verify
    choice=int(input("enter your choice, player " + numPlayer).strip())
TypeError: must be str, not int
>>>

Comment: Try that:

choice=int(input("enter your choice, player " + str(numPlayer)).strip())

Comment: now code works but entering the players choice it shows neither "X" or "0", I don't know I have to figure it out. However thank you for the help, I give you the thumps up for this. Thanks

Comment: thats cuz print_board resets the board again @Kumar Katariya. u have to seperate the initilaization and the print method itself

Comment: @TheFool i dont think so. the board never reset, the board = [" " for i in range(9)] is outside the print_board function

Comment: @ João Castilho so what does this do?   row1="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[0],board[1],board[2])
    row2="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[3],board[4],board[5])
    row3="|{}|{}|{}|".format(board[6],board[7],board[8])

Comment: @TheFool it print's the board with the values of board

Comment: @KumarKatariya swap that line
choice=int(input("enter your choice, player " + str(numPlayer)).strip())
to
choice=int(input("enter your choice, player" + str(numPlayer)+ ": "))


it will work

Comment: @JoãoCastilho sorry but it is not working..  it can't print "X" or "0" on the board selecting the numbers..

Comment: @KumarKatariya if you want, this is the right code, i ran in my computer. Sorry for the previous comments.
https://pastebin.com/DPsf5UGa

Comment: @JoãoCastilho it worked! but there is still one issue, when second player chooses a number, it prints the board 2 times

Comment: @JoãoCastilho It worked! Thank you so much for this, I will go through every line of your code, understand it and compare with my code and will improve.. Cheers

Comment: @JoãoCastilho can you also up vote my question, it will help in my reputation.